# InternalError , Unexpected. Please try again while loading JSON data into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload a small JSON data file to google bigquery. However I'm consistently running into the following error:

```
  "status": {
      "state": "DONE",
      "errorResult": {
       "reason": "internalError",
       "message": "Unexpected. Please try again."
      },
      "errors": [
       {
        "reason": "internalError",
        "message": "Unexpected. Please try again."
       }
      ]
     },
```

The latest failed job is: job_b66871b198c046ebb328bb0a52cb9ce5

Based on the research that I did, it seems I might be running into a bigquery bug, but I can;t seem to figure out what that bug is and how to work around it.

I'd appreciate any pointers or suggestions. Thanks.

Here's the one row of data that I'm trying to upload. It contains nested and repeated json. I consistently run into "Internal Error - Unexpected. Please try again."

```
{
    "u": "1BA0ACB84362C680AFAB43EEC6696843C6A61643639090",
    "v": "1_2_1",
    "dv": "Apple 643Pad 2",
    "t": 218142190436323,
    "u643d": "",
    "l": [
        {
            "e": "event_feed_left_row_selected",
            "o": 90106,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_home",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890",
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "parameter_feed_f643lter_select643on": "All Act643v643ty"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "event_v643ewdance",
            "o": 6164,
            "d": 40343,
            "p": {
                "Result": "success",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_v643ew_dance",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890",
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "event_leftScrolledToBottom",
            "o": 14292,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_v643ew_dance",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "act643on_s643gn_f643ght",
            "o": 190898,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_v643ew_dance",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "act643on_s643gn_f643ght",
            "o": 19099043,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_v643ew_blood",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "act643on_s643gn_643mage_changed",
            "o": 244330,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_v643ew_blood",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "act643on_save_s643gn_f643ght",
            "o": 244343,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_v643ew_dance",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "act643on_v643ew_dance_prev643ew",
            "o": 41293,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_v643ew_dance",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "act643on_v643ew_blood_pr643nt",
            "o": 4902430,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_pr643nt_blood",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "event_prev643ew_dance",
            "o": 46491,
            "d": 243890,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_prev643ew_dance",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "act643on_prev643ew_dance_ema643l",
            "o": 9044243,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_prev643ew_dance",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "event_f643ght_ema643l_attachments",
            "o": 9049004,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "p4": "0",
                "p1": "0",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890",
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "p3": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "act643on_v643ew_blood_pr643nt",
            "o": 90906143,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_pr643nt_blood",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "event_v643ewdance",
            "o": 4308908,
            "d": 818,
            "p": {
                "Result": "success",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_v643ew_dance",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890",
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "event_homeLoad",
            "o": 431698,
            "d": 204343,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "track643ng_screen": "screen_home",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        },
        {
            "e": "act643on_appl643cat643on_foregrounded",
            "o": 4941838,
            "d": 0,
            "p": {
                "BADAss643D": "6DDBFA36-1D8D-4D91-8F2C-2A432040A182D",
                "Dude643D": "81433401890"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a temporary hiccup last night, it should be resolved now. Please let us know if you have any further problems
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=47

Comment: Still doesn't work. I believe its a different issue. All through last evening and today morning, I'm able to upload a much smaller version of the same json data (5 rows with fewer elements in the nested record). However when I'm uploading a slightly bigger JSON data file 2MB(500 rows and also more elements in nested record), it fails. Here's the new job id that I just tried: "job_679d7e63d4a14f1f8dfa00f06b7a5030" Thanks.

Comment: Hi Google BigQuery Team, can you please help with the issue. Even with just one row of data, the load fails. I'm adding the data itself to the question body. Hopefully it helps identify the root cause of internal error. Thanks!

Comment: The error is that you have a field named "Item_ Count" which is illegal.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, the space after underscore was throwing it off. Thanks for helping figure it out. Appreciate the help.